# VBA dynamic numeration in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write code for a dynamic numeration in a column. I insert data with a UserForm from top to bottom (so the new data is always in the second row (first row is for headers).

For column A, I want a numeration for every time I insert data. Let me give you an example:

```
        Numeration   Columns2   Column3     
Row1         2       Value      Value        
Row2                 Value      Value
Row3                 Value      Value
---------------------------------------------------
Row4         1       Value      Value        
Row5                 Value      Value
```

Now, I want a short macro that always inserts into cell A2 the next number. It has to be dynamic, because sometimes I add 3 rows of data and sometimes more or less rows. So it should search column A for the next number, add +1 to it and paste it in cell A2.

I hope it is clear what I want to do.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you not just pick the value of A2 before you do add any rows and then just add 1 to it?

Comment: Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [WorksheetFunction.Max method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.max) to find the maximum in column A and add `+ 1`.

```
With Worksheets("SheetName")
    .Range("A2").Value = WorksheetFunction.Max(.Columns("A")) + 1
End With
```

*Note that `WorksheetFunction.Max` throws an exception if there are e.g. formulas containing errors in column A, so you might want to catch the error using [Error Handling](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling).*

---

**Alternative Solution** (as suggested by Zac)

1. Pick the value of A2 *before* you add rows.
2. Add rows
3. Write picked value + 1

Example:

```
Dim PickValue As Long
PickValue = Worksheets("SheetName").Range("A2").Value

'add your rows here now

Worksheets("SheetName").Range("A2").Value = PickValue + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If your "-----" is added also, you could use the following.

This is my table starting in A1

`=IF(ROW()=1,1,IF(RIGHT(OFFSET(A1,-1,0),1)="-",MAX(OFFSET($B$1,0,0,ROW()-1,1))+1,""))`

You could extend the `right` check also, to say 3 chars = "---" to cover any -ve values if needed.

Comment: Worth to mention that `OFFSET` is volatile and could cause heavy load on calculation if used extensively.